# Extract mean of independent variable interaction from fitted linear model

Tags: r, lm

I try to get the mean of the product (interaction) of two variables from a model fitted with `lm()`.

```
N <- 1000
u <- rnorm(N)
x1 <- rnorm(N)
x2 <- 1 + x1 + rnorm(N)
y <- 1 + x1 + x2 + u
df <- data.frame(y,x1,x2)
fit <- lm(y ~ x1 * x2, data = df)
```

I can calculate the mean of a single variable for a coefficient accessing `$model`.

```
mean(fit$model[,2])
# verify result
mean(df[,2])
```

But how can I get the mean of the interaction without going back into the data.

```
# Result should be
mean(df$x1*df$x2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure *why* you want this, but it is trivial to get from `fit`. First, it is best not to delve into fitted objects like this with `$`. Instead learn to use extractor functions. In this case, the equivalent of `mean(fit$model[,2])` would be, for all columns of the data at once:

```
> colMeans(model.frame(fit))
        y        x1        x2 
2.0783225 0.0283555 1.0481141
```

The model frame is just a copy of the data. What you want is the design matrix, or as R calls it the model matrix, which, unsurprisingly is obtained using the `model.matrix()` function.

```
> head(model.matrix(fit))
  (Intercept)          x1          x2       x1:x2
1           1 -0.33406119  1.95054087 -0.65160001
2           1 -1.41848058  0.35429591 -0.50256186
3           1 -1.32877702 -0.00783884  0.01041607
4           1  0.54054637  1.34637056  0.72777572
5           1 -0.75686319 -0.36476471  0.27607699
6           1  0.04514449  1.62928315  0.07355316
```

Note that the response data aren't in the design matrix, but the interaction term is, in the final column. Use `colMeans()` again to get the mean of each column of this design matrix:

```
> colMeans(model.matrix(fit))
(Intercept)          x1          x2       x1:x2 
  1.0000000   0.0283555   1.0481141   1.0820110
```

For completeness I should show this is correct for my random data set:

```
> colMeans(transform(df[,-1], interaction = x1 * x2))
         x1          x2 interaction 
  0.0283555   1.0481141   1.0820110
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I only wanted the mean for the interaction column and not all columns. I don't know whether accessing it with `colMeans(model.matrix(fit))[3]`, is considered good practice but it is exactly what I needed.

Comment: That would be OK, but overkill if that is all you need: `mean(model.frame(fit)[, 3])` would be more explicit and avoid doing the extract calculations for the other columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
mean(x1 * x2)
#[1] 0.9009494

mean(do.call("*", fit$model[, c("x1", "x2")]))
#[1] 0.9009494

fit <- lm(y ~ x1 * x2, data = df, x=TRUE)
mean(fit$x[,"x1:x2"])
#[1] 0.9009494
```